# $.get VS window.open()

Tags: jquery, window

I have a javascript function in which I want to open a new window and display some data. The problem is I am sending an array of ID's to my action and I do not want to append them to the URL as I can simply pull it as a request paramiter in my action. The logic is as follows.

```
$.get('${studentidurl}', {"registrationIDs[]": rowids}, function(data){
   window.open(data); 
   return false;
});
```

This **DOES NOT WORK** as `window.open();` does not allow for passing additional paramiters to the given URL.

Is there a way to send accross paramiters using window.open() like we would pass paramiters using jquery `$.get(...params go here...)`   ?

Comment: Your question does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to send accross paramiters using window.open() like we
>   would pass paramiters using jquery $.get(...params go here...) ?

Yes, you can specify query string in page directly:

```
window.open('page.html?var1=value1&var2=value2');
```

Here `var1` and `var2` with their values are passed to `page.html` page as an example. You can add as many such name-value pair query string variables as you want. If the values contain spaces or other special characters, then you will have to use [`encodeURIComponent()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp) function.

Comment: URLs have length limits. What options exist if the amount of data you're passing exceeds 2,000+ characters?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you mean. You can pass `GET` parameters in the same way as opening any url. For example, opening `google.com` with the `GET` parameter `q` set to `foo`.

```
window.open('http://www.google.com?q=foo')​
```

Answer (score 0):

What parameter you are trying to pass to the new window, If it is something like some querystring values, you can use like this

```
var newurl = "newpage.aspx?label=34&&pr=154;
myRef = window.open(newurl, 'mywin', 'width=660,height=580,toolbar=0,location=0,resizable=0');
```

If you want to pass some data which you receive from the get call, you can do like this

(Assuming you are getting some id or string from your get method)

```
$.get('${studentidurl}', {"registrationIDs[]": rowids}, function(data){

    var newurl = "newpage.aspx?val="+data;
    myRef = window.open(newurl, 'mywin', 'width=660,height=580,toolbar=0,location=0,resizable=0');
   return false;
});
```